# Sign data using PKCS #7 in JAVA

Tags: java, cryptography, pkcs#7

I want to sign a text file (may be a `.exe` file or something else in the future) 
using PKCS#7 and verify the signature using Java.

1. What do I need to know?
2. Where will I find an API (`.jar` and documentation)?
3. What are the steps I need to follow in order to sign data and verify the data?

Please provide me code snippet if possible.

Comment: Dear user, please revisit [this older question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805385/delete-query-is-not-working-form-java-application). I've voted to close the other question. [Please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377402/how-to-encode-a-value-in-pkcs7-with-java) [do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166159/verifying-pkcs7-certificates-in-java) your homework before asking questions.

Comment: Do you want the signed exe file to be recognized by Windows as signed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I reckon you need the following 2 Bouncy Castle jars to generate the PKCS7 digital signature:

- bcprov-jdk15on-147.jar (for JDK 1.5 - JDK 1.7)
- bcmail-jdk15on-147.jar (for JDK 1.5 - JDK 1.7)

You can download the Bouncy Castle jars from [here](http://bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html).

You need to setup your keystore with the public & private key pair.
You need only the private key to generate the digital signature & the public key to verify it.

Here's how you'd pkcs7 sign content (Exception handling omitted for brevity) :

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaCertStore;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessableByteArray;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSTypedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.ContentSigner;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Store;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;

public final class PKCS7Signer {

    private static final String PATH_TO_KEYSTORE = "/path/to/keyStore";
    private static final String KEY_ALIAS_IN_KEYSTORE = "My_Private_Key";
    private static final String KEYSTORE_PASSWORD = "MyPassword";
    private static final String SIGNATUREALGO = "SHA1withRSA";

    public PKCS7Signer() {
    }

    KeyStore loadKeyStore() throws Exception {

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_KEYSTORE);
        keystore.load(is, KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        return keystore;
    }

    CMSSignedDataGenerator setUpProvider(final KeyStore keystore) throws Exception {

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        Certificate[] certchain = (Certificate[]) keystore.getCertificateChain(KEY_ALIAS_IN_KEYSTORE);

        final List<Certificate> certlist = new ArrayList<Certificate>();

        for (int i = 0, length = certchain == null ? 0 : certchain.length; i < length; i++) {
            certlist.add(certchain[i]);
        }

        Store certstore = new JcaCertStore(certlist);

        Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(KEY_ALIAS_IN_KEYSTORE);

        ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(SIGNATUREALGO).setProvider("BC").
                build((PrivateKey) (keystore.getKey(KEY_ALIAS_IN_KEYSTORE, KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray())));

        CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();

        generator.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").
                build()).build(signer, (X509Certificate) cert));

        generator.addCertificates(certstore);

        return generator;
    }

    byte[] signPkcs7(final byte[] content, final CMSSignedDataGenerator generator) throws Exception {

        CMSTypedData cmsdata = new CMSProcessableByteArray(content);
        CMSSignedData signeddata = generator.generate(cmsdata, true);
        return signeddata.getEncoded();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        PKCS7Signer signer = new PKCS7Signer();
        KeyStore keyStore = signer.loadKeyStore();
        CMSSignedDataGenerator signatureGenerator = signer.setUpProvider(keyStore);
        String content = "some bytes to be signed";
        byte[] signedBytes = signer.signPkcs7(content.getBytes("UTF-8"), signatureGenerator);
        System.out.println("Signed Encoded Bytes: " + new String(Base64.encode(signedBytes)));
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i generate public and private key .
what all algorithm can i use to sign.
we have not mentioned bit length.
can you please provide any study material reference, so that i can understand a2z

Comment: @user1269042, See [Public key Cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) for a start. Google around to find more. Although a bit dated, [Beginning Cryptography with Java](http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Cryptography-Java-David-Hook/dp/0764596330) is an excellent reference.

Comment: You forgot to mention the need for bcpkix-jdk15on-147.jar (now 148) for org.bouncycastle.cms imports.

Comment: you mean that we do not need `bcpkix-jdk15on` ?

Answer (score 4):

PKCS#7 is known as CMS now (Cryptographic Message Syntax), and you will need the Bouncy Castle PKIX libraries to create one. It has ample documentation and a well established mailing list.

I won't supply code snippet, it is against house rules. Try yourself first.

Comment: Current version is called `bcpkix-jdk15on-147.jar`, google it.

Answer (score 0):

With java 8 this is possible to sign in PKCS7 format with presumption you use sun.security.* classes:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.cert.CertPath;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import sun.security.pkcs.ContentInfo;
import sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7;
import sun.security.pkcs.SignerInfo;
import sun.security.util.DerOutputStream;
import sun.security.util.DerValue;
import sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId;
import sun.security.x509.X500Name;



X509Certificate [] certChain = ...; // all certificate chain
X509Certificate c = ...;            // first certificate

PrivateKey privateKey = ...; // private key
//Data to sign
//compute signature:
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
signature.initSign(privateKey);
signature.update(dataToSign);
byte[] signedData = signature.sign();

//load X500Name
X500Name xName = X500Name.asX500Name(c.getIssuerX500Principal());
//load serial number
BigInteger serial = c.getSerialNumber();
//laod digest algorithm
AlgorithmId digestAlgorithmId = new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.SHA256_oid);
//load signing algorithm
AlgorithmId signAlgorithmId = new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.RSAEncryption_oid);

//Create SignerInfo:
SignerInfo sInfo = new SignerInfo(xName, serial, digestAlgorithmId, signAlgorithmId, signedData);
//Create ContentInfo:
ContentInfo cInfo = new ContentInfo(ContentInfo.DATA_OID,
        new DerValue(DerValue.tag_OctetString, dataToSign));
//Create PKCS7 Signed data
PKCS7 p7 = new PKCS7(new AlgorithmId[]{digestAlgorithmId}, cInfo,
        certChain,
        new SignerInfo[]{sInfo});
//Write PKCS7 to bYteArray
DerOutputStream bOut = new DerOutputStream();
p7.encodeSignedData(bOut);
byte[] encodedPKCS7 = bOut.toByteArray();
```