# Can I encrypt, decrypt, sign or verify data using PKCS#7 without Bouncy Castle?

Tags: java, cryptography, pkcs#7

I want to encrypt, decrypt, sign and verify data using PKCS#7 Cryptographic Message Syntax. I saw sample code for this with Bouncy Castle. I want to know can I do this without using the Bouncy Castle libraries?

Comment: There are no mention of PKCS7 in the [section on _Ciphers_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher) in Java's _Standard Algorithm Name Documentation_ so I guess this can't be done without external libraries. [This other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10718419/433835) seems to reinforce this.

Comment: You can always code the algorithm yourself.

Comment: Are you talking about using PKCS#7 *padding*?

Comment: I want encrypt large data like file. this can help encrypt my data without manage blocking. it also known as CMS encryption.

Comment: @HotLicks of course, if you've got a few weeks/months left for implementing an ASN.1 or BER/DER parser/generator, building the structures and testing it against existing implementations...

Comment: @DuncanJones If you look at the title it pretty well rules out PKCS#7 padding. So we are talking about Cryptographic Message Syntax here.

Comment: @owlstead Always worth checking, I've seen some fairly loose usage of terminology here :-)  And speaking as someone who had to partially implement CMS to run on some specialised hardware, I wholeheartedly agree with your other comment!

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for PKCS7 messages in the standard Java libraries. There is no reason not to use an existing implementation like Bouncycastle. It has such a liberal license you can probably just grab it and say you wrote it.

Comment: Of course, you shouldn't *really* say you wrote it. You should include the correct licence text as per the following page: http://www.bouncycastle.org/licence.html. However, the licence is very friendly for commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

You should have fully compatible results using JCE and PKCS5.

Comment: I saw "sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7" recently. does this implement my request?

Comment: You should never use any class from a sun.* package. They are not for public use.