# Sign data in PKCS#7 format using SpongyCastle

Tags: android, digital-signature, bouncycastle, pkcs#7, spongycastle

I'm trying to sign a String in PKCS#7 format with SpongyCastle (using these dependencies `"com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.58.0.0"` and
`"com.madgag.spongycastle:pkix:1.54.0.0"`) in Android.

Here is my key pair generation code:

```
   KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator;
    try {
        Calendar start = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        Calendar end = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 10);
        keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
                .setAlias(ALIAS)
                .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(1))
                .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                .setSubject(new X500Principal(""))
                .build());
        keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            throw e;
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and copied signing code from solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703416/sign-data-using-pkcs-7-in-java) :

```
 CMSSignedDataGenerator setUpProvider(final KeyStore keystore) throws Exception {

    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    Certificate[] certchain = keystore.getCertificateChain(ALIAS);

    final List<Certificate> certlist = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0, length = certchain == null ? 0 : certchain.length; i < length; i++) {
        certlist.add(certchain[i]);
    }

    Store certstore = new JcaCertStore(certlist);

    Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(ALIAS);

    ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider("BC").
            build((PrivateKey) (keystore.getKey(ALIAS, null)));

    CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();

    generator.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").
            build()).build(signer, (X509Certificate) cert));

    generator.addCertificates(certstore);

    return generator;
}
```

but I'm getting `cannot create signer: no such algorithm: SHA1WITHRSA for provider BC` exception.
any hints or sloutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to `setProvider("BC")`. It doesn't crash after removing `setProvider("BC")` from both `JcaContentSignerBuilder` and `JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder`